# Is there any evidence that Maz Kanata's castle was a Jedi temple?

Tags: star-wars, jedi, the-force-awakens

Is there any concrete evidence in *The Force Awakens* or other elements of the Disney canon that Maz Kanata's [castle](http://www.starwars.com/databank/mazs-castle) on Takodana was a Jedi temple?

[image: Maz Kanata's cantina]

It is a towering structure with catacomb-like passages beneath it.  It has existed for at least a thousand years if not much more — Han says in the film that it has been under its current ownership for about one thousand.

Based on its age and configuration, and what was found by Rey in its catacombs, I wonder about the original purpose of the structure.

Comment: Who says the item that was in the catacombs was entrusted by Luke to be there?

Comment: @JackBNimble : Fair point.  I've edited that out.  In the process, it's less spoilery too.  :-)

Comment: What about the fact that the spire over it looks like the Jedi temple, as does the control tower occupied by the Emperor in DS2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't know whether it was specifically a *'temple'*, but we do have confirmation from the canon factbook *[Star Wars: Absolutely Everything You Need to Know, Updated and Expanded](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Absolutely_Everything_You_Need_to_Know,_Updated_and_Expanded)* that the castle was once occupied by the Jedi and that the catacombs contain the tombs of Jedi Knights.

[image]

The fact that the Jedi 'occupied' it would seem to strongly imply that it wasn't build for them and that they (and Maz) were merely residents in the castle, part of a line of successive possessors.

Answer (score 6):

I think we are in the land of speculation here but this is an interesting tidbit about ME-8d9 seen in Maz's castle:

> An ancient protocol droid of unknown manufacture, ME-8D9 has been a fixture at Maz’s castle on Takodana for many years...some whisper that she began her long mechanical life with the Jedi Order.

[image]http://www.starwars.com/databank/me-8d9

Comment: Good find. Also, Maz is entirely too knowledgeable about the Force and Jedi for a random pirate :)

Comment: Maz is supposedly over a thousand years old. Knowledgable, would you not also be, at that age?

Comment: It is hinted in the film and explicit in the book that she has some limited force sensibility.

Comment: I think that droid's look is based on an early concept drawing for C-3PO (perhaps by Ralph McQuarrie). Just a little tidbit.

Answer (score -1):

We can clearly see a tower at the castle in the exact same style as the Jedi Council building on Coruscant and in Clone Wars S3 E 13

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange! Please can you add a bit more evidence (e.g. pictures) to support this answer?

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if this would be a highly regarded argument, but in the Lego force awakens game, when you go through the castle, there is a section of puzzles that involve some robed, Jedi looking dudes, and the Jedi insignia.